# How to merge a spanned volume?

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1, disk-utility, dynamic-disk

I have ended up with my D Volume spanned over multiple partitions (On one physical drive)

How do I merge them?
(They are adjacent).

Or how can I safely get my data off some of the partitions (So I can delete them)

This is the Main drive for a Win 8.1 installation.
(Preferably free, but I can pay a little bit for something that will RELIABLY do this, and also convert back to Basic disk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do it. I backed up the data, recreated one volume and restored everything.

Of course you must make sure that the backup is reliable before deleting the volumes.